# Is there a dashboard indicator for the current VTOL mode?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I have been using the first person mode lately to fly aircraft, and most of them have an indicator to find out if you have the landing gear deployed or retracted. For aircraft with VTOL, I have not seen an indicator for the current fly mode.

Is there a dashboard indicator for seeing the current fly mode on aircraft that can do **V**ertical **T**ake-**o**ff and **L**anding? (example: [Hydra](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Hydra), [Avenger](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Avenger_(plane)))

Comment: Unlike gear up or down, which can be hard to tell in first person, the flying mode should be pretty obvious... I would think your indicator would be whether or not you are moving forward or pitching when moving the stick. I'll admit I don't fly in first person much, and when I do, I have the camera mode set to hood view so it's a little more realistic.